# TypeError: Class constructor RegisterPage cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Encountering this issue when trying to test app in browser, been a little while since i've used react so i'm a bit rusty with any changes that've come in the last year, i've done a little research on es6 and still not able to solve this issue

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
// import useForm from 'react-hook-form';


class RegisterPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            user: {
                username: '',
                firstName: '', 
                lastName: '',
                email: '',
                password: ''
            },
            submitted: false
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

    handleChange(e) {
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        const { user } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            user: 
                user,
                [name]: value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({submitted: true});
        const { user } = this.state;
        if (user.firstName && user.lastName && user.email && user.username && user.password) {
            this.props.register(user);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {user, submitted} = this.state;
        return(
            <div >
                <h2>Register</h2>
                <form name ="loginForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}></form>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.firstName ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="firstName" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                            <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                        }
                </div>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.lastName ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" value={user.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.lastName &&
                            <div className="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>

                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.username ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" value={user.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.username &&
                            <div className="help-block">Username is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>

                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.email ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="email">email</label>
                        <input type="text" className="form-control" name="email" value={user.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.email &&
                            <div className="help-block">Email is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>

                    <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.password ? ' has-error' : '')}>
                        <label htmlFor="Password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" value={user.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                            <div className="help-block">Password is required</div>
                        }
                    </div>


            </div>
        );
    }

}
export default RegisterPage;
```

I've tried editing my babel settings in my pack.json to configure them for ES6

Comment: Where and how are you using `RegisterPage`?

Comment: I'm routing it within my app.js

Comment: `'import RegisterPage from './Views/Register/Register';`

`function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <div className="container">
            <Route exact path="/register">{RegisterPage}</Route>

          </div>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}`

Comment: Try `<RegisterPage />` instead of `{RegisterPage}`

Comment: that actually worked, was there a specific change since mid 2020 that made it work this way?

Comment: Not that I know of, that as far as I know has always been the way to place a class react component